# Using looped panoramic picture as website background

Tags: html

I'm trying to set this photo: [Photo](http://xn--wiatalkoholi-mlc.com.pl/bg.jpg) as my website background. I is supposed to look something like this [example](http://html5up.net/uploads/demos/aerial/)

Comment: If you ask a question you should post some kind of html, css, javascript that you have done so people can work with you from there.

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855863/animation-slide-image-from-left-to-right?noredirect=1#comment42292055_26855863 The idea is the same. You'll have to work on making it loop though. It will have a line that looks funky when the image repeats.

Comment: Ok. I got to something like this http://xn--wiatalkoholi-mlc.com.pl/test.html   with this: http://pastebin.com/sKJ3nVfg piece of code. now I can't get this to fit vertically not horizontally. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Clint Powell. Finally got it all working and it's pure css and the code is very simple.

Here is [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/fd7c0g4c/30/).